# Assign specific values from return in python

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables, return-value, local

I new to all python terminology and I may use incorrect terms.
I would be glad of any correctness.
Here is related code:

```
def func(a,b):
    counter = 0
    sum = a+b
    counter += 1
    return sum, counter
```

Now, suppose I only want the counter variable, how can I assign it to global variable (hope the term is correct)?

Another question, if the function returns a few variables and I want only a few of them how shall I do this?

I saw something like this:

```
new_sum = func(sum)
```

But when I do this it expects me to write a & b.
I'm a bit confusing...

Basically,  I want to use the variables that I made in the functions outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

1. use `global`  to tell python that a var is global.
2. Multiple val return in python is tuple.

See below for what you are looking for:

```
>>> counter = 0
>>> def func(a,b):
...     sum = a+b
...     global counter
...     counter = counter + 1
...     print("global counter: ", counter)
...     return sum, counter
...
>>> func(2,3)
global counter:  1
(5, 1)
>>> func(2,4)
global counter:  2
(6, 2)
>>> func(2,6)
global counter:  3
(8, 3)
>>> sum,count = func(2,6)
global counter:  4
>>> sum
8
>>> count
4
>>> type(func(2,6))
global counter:  5
<class 'tuple'>
>>>
```

Comment: According to your example... each assignment calls the function over and over.... what if the function produces a large output or suing an api and I don't want to use it so many times

Comment: @Racheli That is to demonstrate how global variable works, it retains the values over multiple calls. It's the same function you have written.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question about declaring global variables, although this isn't exactly recommendable, here's how it can be done:

```
counter = 0
def func(a,b):
    global counter
    #print(counter) gives 0
    sum = a+b
    counter += 1
    return sum, counter
```

As for your second question, because you declared your function to take in 2 input arguments, you must past 2 separate values in. For example, this is how you can use the function to return in the sum of 5 and 10:

```
a = 5
b = 10
result = func(a,b)
print(result)
```

Where result will be a tuple with 2 values: sum (15) and counter (1). Also, note that declaring counter as a global value modifies the value of counter itself, so it isn't necessary to return the value of counter (the updated value can simply be indexed in the script). Hope this helps!

Comment: It helps, thanks! What if  a function returns 5 values and I only want the second value and the forth. As @drd wrote  `sum,count = func(2,6)`. How do I assign certain values?

Comment: You can use a dummy variable to "catch" the unwanted variable(s) like so:
`_, var2, var3, var4, var5 = f(x,y)`. Even better, you can try `var2, var3, var4, var5 = f(x,y)[1:]`, which captures output from the function starting from the second value.

Comment: Something like this will be good too? `var = (f(x,y)[1])` cause it's a tuple, isn't it?

Comment: Absolutely, brackets aren't necessary though

Comment: According to the example... I understand that each assignment calls the function over and over.... what if the function produces a large output or using an api and I don't want to use it so many times...

Comment: You could save the output to a tuple, and then separately index the relevant values. `array = f(x,y)` then `var1, var2 = array[1], array[2]`.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do when dealing with multiple return values is this:

```
counter = 0 ##global variable
def func(a,b):
    counter = 0
    sum = a+b
    counter += 1
    return sum, counter, val3, val4, val5

return_value = func(a,b) ##assign result to a variable
```

You can then access your function values simply by;

```
##multiple line solution
new_sum = return_value[0]
new_counter = return_value[1]
new_val3 = return_value[2]

##single line solution
sum, counter, val3, val4, val5 = return_value

## code to do sth with sum, counter, val3 ....
```